# Poner contador a campo repetido en Java

Tags: java, json

tengo un problema con java. Muy resumidamente sería mostrar una lista de usuarios por su nombre (extraidos de un fichero .json), pero les debo añadir a todos un sufijo 00, quedando así: 'nombre+00'. De esta manera, si existen 2 usuarios con el mismo nombre entonces el programa debería diferenciarlos incrementando el sufijo. Por ejemplo, si dos usuarios se llaman 'Pepe', el nombre debería quedar así: 'pepe00' y 'pepe01'.

Esto es un resumen de lo que tengo hecho:

**Clase User:**

```
public class User{

    private String name;


    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

**Clase Datos:**

```
private HashMap<String, List<User>> readUsers() {
    HashMap<String, List<User>> usuarios= new HashMap<>();

    SimpleFeatureCollection collection = datastore.getFeatureCollection();

    try (SimpleFeatureIterator itrusuarios = collection.features()) {

        int contador=0;
        while (itrusuarios.hasNext()) {

            SimpleFeature simpleFeature = itrusuarios.next();
            User usuario = new User();

           usuario.setName(simpleFeature.getID()+contador); //Esto no funciona bien
            contador++;

            System.out.println(construction);
        }

    } finally {
        datastore.dispose();
    }


    return usuarios;
}
```

Si intento añadir el contador al nombre del usuario (en la clase Datos), no funciona como debería, ya que me muestra toda la lista de usuarios, y les va añadiendo un número que se autoincrementa: Rosa1, Pepe2, Pepe3, Juan4, Ana5...

Si modifico el setter de la clase User con un contador: `this.name = name+contador;` entonces me queda así: Rosa0, Pepe0, Pepe0, Juan0, Ana0...

La salida que yo busco sería:

> Rosa00, Pepe00, Pepe01, Juan00, Ana00...

Es decir, cuando encuentre el mismo nombre, que sóle le incremente a ese registro.

Gracias!

Answer (score 1):

Te pongo un ejemplo de como podrías hacerlo:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    HashMap<String, Object> lista = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    List<String> nombres = new ArrayList<String>();

    nombres.add("Rosa");
    nombres.add("Pepe");
    nombres.add("Pepe");
    nombres.add("Ana");

    for (String nombre : nombres) {

        int contador = 0;

        String nombreModificado = nombre + String.format("%02d", contador);

        while (lista.get(nombreModificado) != null) {

            contador++;
            nombreModificado = nombre + String.format("%02d", contador);
        }

        lista.put(nombreModificado, new Object());

        System.out.println(nombreModificado);
    }

}
```

La salida por pantalla del código es el siguiente:

> Rosa00 Pepe00 Pepe01 Ana00

No te debería de costar mucho adaptarlo a tu código.

Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Te propongo la siguiente solucion sobre tu código:

```
private HashMap<String, List<User>> readUsers() {
    HashMap<String, List<User>> usuarios= new HashMap<>();

    SimpleFeatureCollection collection = datastore.getFeatureCollection();

    try (SimpleFeatureIterator itrusuarios = collection.features()) {

        int contador=0;
        while (itrusuarios.hasNext()) {

            SimpleFeature simpleFeature = itrusuarios.next();
            User usuario = new User();

            String usuarioExistente = "";

            //Modificación
            if(contador <= 9) {
                usuarioExistente = "0".concat(String.valueOf(contador));
            }else {
                usuarioExistente = String.valueOf(contador);
            }

           usuario.setName(simpleFeature.getID()+usuarioExistente); //Esto no funciona bien
           //Modificación
            contador++;

            System.out.println(construction);
        }

    } finally {
        datastore.dispose();
    }


    return usuarios;
}
```

Con este simple cambio puede que te funcione como quieres.